# LOAD DATA INFILE convert 2 dates using STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%m/%d/%Y') - throws error

Tags: mysql

This is throwing an error, I am unable to figure out why, any ideas?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H:/Data/DB__Muni/data/msrb_AZ_short1.csv'
INTO TABLE import_mdrp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
  ( 
    Issuer, cusip6, state, Issue,
    page_pointer, @var1, date_rng, cusip9, @var2,
    yield, Amt_Offer_Dlr, Amt_Offer_Per, Security_Description,
    Fitch, Moody, cusip_img, fitch_img, moody_img 
  )
SET maturity = STR_TO_DATE(@var2,'%m/%d/%Y') 
SET issue_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%m/%d/%Y') 
;
```

Comment: If I use either SET.... stmt it works, but when I add both I get the error. I have tried using a comma, still get error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
SET maturity = STR_TO_DATE(@var2,'%m/%d/%Y') 
SET issue_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

try

```
SET maturity = STR_TO_DATE(@var2,'%Y-%m-%d') 
SET issue_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SET maturity = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    issue_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: The parameter to `STR_TO_DATE()` is the _input_ date format which transforms to the MySQL native format, not the _output_ date format to match the native MySQL format.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET i
ssue_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d')' at line 10

Comment: Please see my edited query.  One of the comments on [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)  was talking about similar issue.

Comment: I believe you used twice the syntax `SET` and you should do it once.  Also (not sure though), you were inputting the US time standard and, since MySQL keeps the date in ISO standard, this might also confuse it a bit.

If you accepted my answer, please tick to close the question.